# Cron job image import issue - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, import, image, cronjobs

In Magento 2.3, I am importing data from the **.xml** file. The product name, SKU and product description i can import via cron job but I cannot import the product image. Can you help me?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: share the cronjob script you have used to import product details

Comment: $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
$product->save();

Comment: What is the format of `$filePath`?

Comment: It's absolute path